# How to align rightly the numbers in NumberPicker android?

Tags: android, numberpicker, right-align

I have added two NumberPickers in AlertDialog.Builder. I tried to make the NumberPicker text aligned right. But i could not.!

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/minimum_value"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why not just make the whole number picker aligned right? (Seperating the label if need be)

Comment: can u post your layout xml?

Comment: Sorry Yuva i could not post full code.. its for the one number picker same set repeated to another one also..

Comment: Nobody have answer..?

Answer (score 0):

```
I could not align it right. But i made some tricky work. My code is below..


<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:paddingLeft="500dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/transparent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/numberPicker1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/minimum_value"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:fadingEdge="none" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```